# error when trying to upload application with nodejs

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\PRJ\FINI\front-end/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\PRJ\FINI\front-end\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\meu.nome\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-06-18T10_50_32_530Z-debug-0.log

Comment: well do you have a package.json file in the respective folder?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.